# Debugging C++ code behind python module created with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb, pybind11

I would like to use `gdb` to debug some `c++` code that is behind a python module defined using `pybind11`.

For the sake of simplicity, consider the python module available [here](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example).

I have created a virtual environment with `venv` and `python3.12.2` and I have installed the python module as suggested in the `README.md` file of the git repo by running the command `python3 -m pip install cmake_example`. The module is working from `python` as expected.

Now consider the following simple script `main.py`:

```
import cmake_example

print(f"3 + 5 = {cmake_example.add(3,5)}")
```

I would like to run this script and stop within the function `add` ([here](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/62fe6fcc27824ba6fc4492a624a502aa3d82ed4e/src/main.cpp#L7)). Is it possible?

I have tried to run `gdb python3` and to set the breakpoint but I got the following message:

```
(gdb) break cmake_example/src/main.cpp:6
No source file named cmake_example/src/main.cpp.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])
```

Even if I press `y`, when I run the script `main.py` it does not stop and the code is executed until the end

Comment: Are you sure you have build your `cmake_example` project in debug?

Comment: yes, I added `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")` to the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the `cmake_example` directory

Comment: How do you run `main.py`?